# Importing ng2-select in angular2-rc.7 webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, ng2-bootstrap

Using webpack and I installed ng2-select using npm and I have the ng2-bootstrap installed and working fine. but I get the following error in my console when I imported ng2-select

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'SelectComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'

This is my **app.module.ts** file:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { SELECT_DIRECTIVES } from "ng2-select/ng2-select";

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, Ng2BootstrapModule, SELECT_DIRECTIVES],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    styleUrls: ['app/assets/ng2-select.css'],
    templateUrl: '<ng-select [items]="items" placeholder="Country">
                </ng-select>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    public items: Array<string> = ['Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia',
    'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'England', 'Egypt', 'Finland', 'France',
    'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Netherlands',
    'Poland', 'Spain'];

}
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to import `SelectModule` in your AppModule to make it work, and remove `SELECT_DIRECTIVES`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, Ng2BootstrapModule, SelectModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

see the [npm package readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-select#usage) for more details.

Comment: I am using ng2-select ( http://valor-software.com/ng2-select/ ) not angular2-select

Comment: Problem is that this lib is using angular2 rc1. Maybe putting   `SELECT_DIRECTIVES`  in declarations could fix your problem, otherwise you'll have to wait for a module.

Comment: Worked with `SelectModule` in RC7. Thanks!